NGINX Basic Auth & proxy pass
I am trying to find the appropriate NGINX configuration in order to apply Basic Auth at the /location and pass (proxy_pass) the locations to the appropriate path, avoiding any CORS.
default.conf: |
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file   .htpasswd;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://www.test1.com:84;
    }

    location /my/account {
        
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        proxy_pass http://www.test1.com:84/my/account;
    }

    location /imageproperties/listing {
        
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        proxy_pass http://www.test1.com:84/imageproperties/listing;
    }

    location /imageproperties/selling {
        
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        proxy_pass http://www.test1.com:84/imageproperties/buying;
    }        
}

Is there any regex that can replace the location /imageproperties and use proxy_pass that will pass all requests via the location.
thank you.
